# CLI StdIn Scala

Tags: scala, command-line-interface, stdin, slick

I have created a console-interface application as todo-list in Scala. My data access layer works with Slick 3 and my interface works using simple StdIn methods. But I have some troubles with reading lines. My main menu works fine while inner menu acts weirdly sometimes. In particular, when I enter a command for the first time I do not get any result just the same menu is displayed again. Then I enter any command and I get the result. And if I try to enter some command for the 3d time my program just stops with System.exit. 
Here is the code for my interface:

```
object UserInterface {
  def displayMainMenu(): Unit ={
    println("Main menu:" + " \n1 - Login" + "\n2 - Exit")
    println("\nChoose the operation you want to perform:")
    val inputMainMenu = readInt()
    buildMainMenu(inputMainMenu)
  }

  def buildMainMenu(inputNumber: Int) =  inputNumber match {
    case 1 => enterSystem()
    case 2 => System.exit(0)
    case _ => println("Your input was wrong. Try again"); displayMainMenu()
  }

  def enterSystem(): Unit ={
    println("Input you login, please:")
    val inputLogin = readLine()
    println("Input you password, please:")
    val inputPassword = readLine()

    val checkLogin = Await.result(DAO.checkUserLogin(inputLogin, inputPassword), Duration.Inf).toString
    val userId = DAO.selectUserId(inputLogin)

    def changeOutputs(checkLogin: String):Unit = checkLogin match {
      case "true" => println("You have successfully entered"); displayInnerMenu(); buildMenu(userId)
      case "false" => println("Your input for login or password is wrong. Please, try again"); displayMainMenu()
      case _ => println("Your input is wrong"); displayMainMenu()
    }
    changeOutputs(checkLogin)
  }

  def buildMenu(userId: Long): Unit ={
    def chooseOption(number: Int):Unit = number match {
      case 1 => displayFinishedTasks(userId)
      case 2 => displayUnfinishedTasks(userId)
      case 3 => addTask(userId)
      case 4 => deleteTask()
      case 5 => markTaskAsFinished(userId)
      case 6 => displayMainMenu()
      case _ => println("Your input is wrong"); displayMainMenu()
    }
    val inputNum = displayInnerMenu()
    chooseOption(inputNum)

  }

  def displayInnerMenu():Int ={
    println("TODO List:" + "\n1 - Display finished tasks" + "\n2 - Display unfinished tasks"
      + "\n3 - Add task" + "\n4 - Delete task" + "\n5 - Mark task as finished" + "\n6 - Get back to the main menu")
    println("\nChoose the operation you want to perform:")
    val inputNum = readInt()
    inputNum
  }

  def displayAllTasks(id: Long) = {
    println()
    println("User's tasks:\n" + Await.result(DAO.selectTasksByUser(id), Duration.Inf).toList.toString)
    displayInnerMenu()
  }

  def displayFinishedTasks(id: Long) = {
    println()
    println("User's finished tasks:\n" + Await.result(DAO.selectFinishedTasks(id), Duration.Inf).toList.toString)
    displayInnerMenu()
  }

  def displayUnfinishedTasks(id: Long) = {
    println()
    println("User's unfinished tasks:\n" + Await.result(DAO.selectUnfinishedTasks(id), Duration.Inf).toList.toString)
    displayInnerMenu()
  }

  def addTask(id: Long) = {
    println()
    println("Input the task name you want to create, please:")
    val taskName = readLine()
    Await.result(DAO.addTask(taskName, id), Duration.Inf)
    displayInnerMenu()
  }

  def deleteTask() = {
    println()
    println("Choose the task you want to delete, please:")
    val taskId = readLong()
    Await.result(DAO.deleteTask(Some(taskId)), Duration.Inf)
    displayInnerMenu()
  }

  def markTaskAsFinished(id: Long) = {
    println()
    println("Choose the task you want to mark as finished, please:")
    val taskId = readLong()
    Await.result(DAO.finishTask(Some(taskId), id), Duration.Inf)
    displayInnerMenu()
  }

}
```

What I want is some kind of infinite cycle so I could perform my commands as many times as I need or set the limit. So what changes I can introduce in this code? I would be very grateful for some help!

Answer (score 1):

Your particular troubles seem to come from the fact that `changeOutputs` in 
 `enterSystem` calls `displayInnerMenu` which reads an `Int` from input but does nothing useful with it. Probably you should have called `buildMenu` in most of the places where `displayInnerMenu` is called.

Also it seems that you should improve your debugging skills. This is a crucial skill and this code is not that hard to debug.

Taken more broadly this is a complicated topic with no simple best answer. But there are certainly bad ones and unfortunately yours is one of those. The thing I don't like most in your code is big separation in the code between the menu item title and menu item action. (Just imagine what it takes to add new menu item in the middle. Or what would it take to create a deeper menu with some items shared between levels.) So I would re-write most of the code. Being more of an OOP-guy than a FP-guy, I would do something like this:

```
object UserInterface {

  // should be non-generic for simplicity of the rest of the code
  trait MenuAndStateNG {
    def runMenu(): MenuAndStateNG
  }

  trait MenuItem[S] {
    val name: String

    def doAction(state: S, curMenu: MenuAndStateNG): MenuAndStateNG
  }

  case class Menu[S](header: String, items: Seq[MenuItem[S]]) {}

  case class MenuAndState[S](menu: Menu[S], state: S) extends MenuAndStateNG {

    def runMenu(): MenuAndStateNG = {
      var inputNum: Int = -1
      var isFirstRun = true

      // we use 1-based indices in the menu
      while (inputNum <= 0 || inputNum > menu.items.length) {
        if (!isFirstRun) {
          println("Your input was wrong. Try again")
        }
        isFirstRun = false

        println(menu.header + ":")
        println(menu.items.zipWithIndex.map({ case (item, index) => s"${index + 1} - ${item.name}" }).mkString("\n"))
        println("Choose the operation you want to perform:")

        inputNum = StdIn.readInt()
      }
      println()
      val nextMenu = menu.items(inputNum - 1).doAction(state, this)
      nextMenu
    }
  }


  // most of menu items doesn't change current menu
  // let's make it easier to implement
  trait SimpleMenuItem[S] extends MenuItem[S] {
    override def doAction(state: S, curMenu: MenuAndStateNG): MenuAndStateNG = {
      doSimpleAction(state)
      curMenu
    }

    def doSimpleAction(state: S): Unit
  }


  def start(): Unit = {
    var curMenu: MenuAndStateNG = MenuAndState(mainMenu, ())
    var isFirstRun = true
    while (true) {
      if (!isFirstRun) {
        println
      }
      isFirstRun = false
      curMenu = curMenu.runMenu()
    }
  }


  private val loginItem = new MenuItem[Unit] {
    override val name = "Login"

    override def doAction(state: Unit, curMenu: MenuAndStateNG): MenuAndStateNG = {
      println("Input you login, please:")
      val inputLogin = StdIn.readLine()
      println("Input you password, please:")
      val inputPassword = StdIn.readLine()

      val checkLogin = Await.result(DAO.checkUserLogin(inputLogin, inputPassword), Duration.Inf).toString
      val userId = DAO.selectUserId(inputLogin)

      checkLogin match {
        case "true" =>
          println("You have successfully entered")
          MenuAndState(userMenu, userId)
        case "false" =>
          println("Your input for login or password is wrong. Please, try again")
          curMenu
        case _ =>
          println("Your input is wrong")
          curMenu
      }
    }
  }

  private val exitItem = new MenuItem[Unit] {
    override val name = "Exit"

    override def doAction(state: Unit, curMenu: MenuAndStateNG): MenuAndStateNG = {
      System.exit(0)
      null // null is bad but it doesn't matter by now
    }
  }


  private val displayFinishedTasks = new SimpleMenuItem[Int] {
    override val name: String = "Display finished tasks"

    override def doSimpleAction(state: Int): Unit = {
      println("User's finished tasks:\n" + Await.result(DAO.selectFinishedTasks(id), Duration.Inf).toList.toString)
    }
  }

  private val displayUnfinishedTasks = new SimpleMenuItem[Int] {
    override val name: String = "Display unfinished tasks"

    override def doSimpleAction(state: Int): Unit = {
      println("User's unfinished tasks:\n" + Await.result(DAO.selectUnfinishedTasks(id), Duration.Inf).toList.toString)
    }
  }

  private val displayAllTasks = new SimpleMenuItem[Int] {
    override val name: String = "Display all tasks"

    override def doSimpleAction(state: Int): Unit = {
      println("User's tasks:\n" + Await.result(DAO.selectTasksByUser(id), Duration.Inf).toList.toString)
    }
  }

  private val addTask = new SimpleMenuItem[Int] {
    override val name: String = "Add task"

    override def doSimpleAction(state: Int): Unit = {
      println("Input the task name you want to create, please:")
      val taskName = readLine()
      Await.result(DAO.addTask(taskName, id), Duration.Inf)
    }
  }
  private val deleteTask = new SimpleMenuItem[Int] {
    override val name: String = "Delete task"

    override def doSimpleAction(state: Int): Unit = {
      println("Choose the task you want to delete, please:")
      val taskId = readLong()
      Await.result(DAO.deleteTask(Some(taskId)), Duration.Inf)
    }
  }

  private val markTaskFinished = new SimpleMenuItem[Int] {
    override val name: String = "Mark task as finished"

    override def doSimpleAction(state: Int): Unit = {
      println("Choose the task you want to mark as finished, please:")
      val taskId = readLong()
      Await.result(DAO.finishTask(Some(taskId), id), Duration.Inf)
    }
  }

  private val logoutTask = new MenuItem[Int] {
    override val name = "Get back to the main menu"

    override def doAction(state: Int, curMenu: MenuAndStateNG): MenuAndState[Unit] = {
      MenuAndState(mainMenu, ())
    }
  }

  val mainMenu: Menu[Unit] = Menu("Main menu", List(loginItem, exitItem))

  val userMenu: Menu[Int] = Menu("User menu", List(
    displayAllTasks,
    displayFinishedTasks,
    displayUnfinishedTasks,
    addTask,
    deleteTask,
    markTaskFinished,
    logoutTask))

}
```

The main ideas are following:

1. Join menu action and title into a single `MenuItem`
2. Let the `MenuItem` select next "menu state" (`MenuAndState`)
3. `MenuAndState` from the outside looks like `MenuAndStateNG` - i.e. something that just can be run to get next `MenuAndStateNG`. From the inside it is split into a "fixed part" (`Menu`) = header + list of items and "variable part" = `state`. By introducing this separation I was able to make `userMenu` actually a constant rather than `def`
4. Most of the menu items doesn't change menu and just return to their parent. To simplify code for this scenario `curMenu` is passed as an argument to the `doAction` and there is a `SimpleMenuItem` that just always returns it\

Given such design all you need is:

1. create a `val` for each menu item
2. create `mainMenu` and `userMenu` `val`s  effectively as lists of those menu items
3. run an infinite loop starting from the `mainMenu` (done in `start`)

Note that because `MenuAndStateNG` returns the next `MenuAndStateNG` from its `runMenu` I can use an infinite loop instead of deepening the stack on each menu iteration (which is generally a bad idea).

Comment: It's a good code. But I am looking for a more functional approach